# Branch.io error Cannot encode value

Tags: ios, swift, branch.io

I'm using Branch.io for deep linking and referrals/rewards and I've started getting this error:

```
Cannot encode value {
"/v1/open-brtt" = 11701;
}, type is in not list of accepted types
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation of it, and I'm not even certain where it's coming from, since it pops up in the console while the app is idling. (Maybe something is timing-out?) Honestly, I only *suspect* it's Branch because it's come up since adding Branch, and the "/v1/" format is similar to other Branch strings.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here: this definitely looks like something from our SDK. Could you submit a ticket to our [integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) with more details? I think we'll probably need to see more of your code and backend session logs for debugging.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I'm going to see if I can track down any of my code directly connected to it (since it will make my ticket more useful). Do you know what "/v1/open-brtt" might relate to, by any chance?

Comment: It would be caused when your app first launches, probably somewhere related to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. `/v1/open` is the API endpoint we use to record the app open event, but I'm not sure where the `-brtt` part is coming from.

Comment: Well, I'm really not doing anything in there. Basically just getInstance(), initSessionWithLaunchOptions(), and BranchWelcomeViewController.shouldShowWelcome(params)...

Comment: I doubt this is anything you're doing... Possibly a bug on our end. If you can submit that ticket with your config details, it would be very helpful :)

Comment: Just to update this thread. Branch got back on my ticket; these are just log messages. Nothing actually going wrong.